# setcookie() doesn't create cookie on www.domain.tld but works on domain.tld

Tags: php, cookies

I've searched everywhere and tried everything.
If you log in on http://r4ge.ro it works. If you go to www.r4ge.ro the cookie is read and works.
If you log out, then try to log in on www.r4ge.ro the cookie is never created.

```
    $data = "name=" . $jucatoru . "&pass=" . md5($passw);
    $date_of_expiry = time()+60*60*24 ;
    setcookie ( $cookie, $data, $date_of_expiry, "/", ".r4ge.ro");
    echo "Succesfully logged in";
    exit();
```

I've checked and it's not a reading problem, the cookie doesn't exist if you try to log in from www.r4ge.ro. Tested on chrome and firefox (site doesn't work on IE)

This is how the logout is done

```
    $date_of_expiry = time() - 60 ;
    setcookie( $cookie, "nothing", $date_of_expiry, "/", ".r4ge.ro");
    echo "Succesfully logged out!
```

And this is how the cookie is read

```
$data = $_COOKIE[$cookie];
parse_str($data, $output);
$name = $output['name'];
$pass = $output['pass'];
```

Test credentials: test : test1 if you want to try it out yourselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer this even tho the answer is unsatisfactory as hell.

I've written a letter to my hosting provider and they provided two solutions:

- Create two separate cookies for www and non www (dumb)
- Use .htaccess to redirect from www to non www (still dumb but apparently everyone does it because hurr durr duplicate content[you can even try www.stackoverflow.com])

To save everyone with this problem another google search, here's the script you need to add to .htaccess to redirect from www to non www without specifying domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If someone knows the answer to the cookie issue, please post that too.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser won't let you set a cookie for a domain that's 'higher' than the URL you're currently on.  You're trying to set a cookie on `r4ge.ro`, which works fine when you're *on* `r4ge.ro`, but when you load the page from `www.r4g3.ro` you can only set cookies for `www.r4ge.ro` or below (eg `foo.www.r4ge.ro`).  It becomes more obvious if you imagine you had a site `example.co.uk`, and on that site you tried to set a cookie for the `co.uk` domain: that would definitely be dangerous, because that cookie could then be read (and used to track your browsing habits) from *any* `.co.uk` domain.

If you omit the final parameter from `setcookie()` then it will set for the current site, which will work (if you log in on the `www` subdomain you will not then be logged in on the top domain, but all other permutations will work).

Comment: I'm fairly sure a subdomain can set a `.example.com` cookie.

Comment: when posting answers, please add a code example too. I'm pretty sure I'm too dumb to understand. From the docs, I understood that you can set a cookie's domain to be anything (from any domain) and that if I set it to r4ge.ro(.r4ge.ro) it will work on anything higher. Just for testing purposes, I'll try to make two different cookies, one for www and one for ... well, you get it. Let's see how that works out edit::well I don't really understand anymore. Not even setcookie ( $cookie, $data, $date_of_expiry, "/", "www.r4ge.ro"); will work on www.r4ge.ro , I'll check if it's the host's fault